# Check in C# whether php soap returned soapFault

Tags: c#, php, soap, web-services, soapfault

I have problem with checking SoapFault response from writen in PHP Soap webservice.
Responce looks like this (default "throw new SoapFault("SOAP:CLIENT", "Bad login");"

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <SOAP-ENV:Fault>
        <faultcode>SOAP:CLIENT</faultcode>
        <faultstring>Bad login</faultstring>
    </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

And C# code looks like this:

```
try
{
   //creating new webservice, filling headers and alling something
   webservice = new...
   items = webservice.getSth();
}
catch ( Exception ex )
{
   MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); -> "Namespace prefix 'SOAP' not defined"
}
```

When login/pass/apikey etc is OK than i get what i need, but when sth is wrong than i cant display proper information.

How to check if SOAP returned fault?
I googled for the problem, but couldnt find valuable information.

Unfortunetly i cant change webservice.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
catch (SoapException ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Detail.OuterXml);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunetly SoapException is empty, when i use
try { .. }  
catch(SoapException ex ) { .. }  
catch(Exception ex) { .. }  
it goes straight to Exception
Tried even with XmlExceptions but they also were "empty"

Comment: Edit: dont know why, but after hundreds of compilations it started to work :/
Thx anyway :)